# pipedrive-python-lib - how to get deals based on filter

Tags: python, pipedrive-api

I use pipedrive-python-lib (https://github.com/GearPlug/pipedrive-python) 
to connect with Pipeline API.

Question: 
I want to get only deals based on filter.

Problem:
When I get deals data I don't see any info about filters.
And when I get specify filter by:

```
pipeline_filter = client.filters.get_filter('15')     # get filter with id
```

I have only details about this filter.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, find the answer.

I need to add metod to deals.py:

```
def get_all_deals_with_filter(self, filter_id, **kwargs):
    url = 'deals?filter_id={}'.format(filter_id)
    return self._client._get(self._client.BASE_URL + url, **kwargs)
```